# Mysql binlog not readable

Tags: mysql

My replication broke giving me this error

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I am trying to see for which value that foreign key failed, but when I am reading this binlog, I get this unreadable characters - My replication binlog-format is ROW. How do I get to know for which row the replication is failing ?

## 121008 14:09:31 server id 372059  end_log_pos 52230307         Table_map: `magento`.`catalogsearch_result` mapped to number 305

## 121008 14:09:31 server id 372059  end_log_pos 52230355         Write_rows: table id 305 flags: STMT_END_F

BINLOG '
6yRzUBNbrQUAQgAAAKP4HAMAADEBAAAAAAEAB21hZ2VudG8AFGNhdGFsb2dzZWFyY2hfcmVzdWx0
AAMDA/YCFAQA
6yRzUBdbrQUAMAAAANP4HAMAADEBAAAAAAEAA//4IWwSAClUAACAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: The last one seems incomplete, base64_decoding that does not give me a valid table name. Did you run out of disk space? If not you can probably re-download the original binlog from the server you're replicating from, that might still be in good condition.

Comment: which one do you want me to get ? In the binlog I am not getting the actual SQL statements - I get this funky characters in the binlog when I read it with mysqlbinlog tool - What did you mean by base64_decoding ? what is that ?

Comment: `php -r 'echo base64_decode("6yRzUBNbrQUAQgAAAKP4HAMAADEBAAAAAAEAB21hZ2VudG8AFGNhdGFsb2dzZWFyY2hfcmVzdWx0 AAMDA/YCFAQA ");'`
I get:
`�$sP[�B��1magentocatalogsearch_result�` that's your first entry in the binlog paste in case you're wondering

Comment: well, I did not understand what you are saying...how do I decode like the way you did ? does it run on my linux or any other outside tool ? also when replication fails should I look into end_log_pos or Exec_Master_Log_Pos ?

Comment: look on any copies of the binlog you have, if any is different from this you might use that to restore your replication to a working state, there are tutorials on how to do this on the net, it would be a long discussion as there are very many things you can do depending on each thing that works/fails.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could output the binlog using one of these switches:

--base64-output=never

OR

--base64-output=decode-rows

From the mySQL manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_base64-output

Should help make your binlog output more readable. Note that decode-rows will omit anything that it can't decode though...